# How to filter on a xml node name keeping the tree structure?

Tags: c#, xml, linq, linq-to-xml

I want to retrieve a tree structure (or a node structure) from a xml file, ignoring some element. In the example I just want to get the Folder nodes.

```
<Folder name="users">
     <Folder name="user1">
        <File name="file1.txt"></File>
        <Folder name="mydocuments">...</Folder>
     </Folder>
</Folder>
<Folder name="windows"></Folder>
<Folder name="temp"></Folder>
```

But I want to keep the "tree" of the folder nodes and note lose it using a method like :

```
var folders = doc.Descendants().Where(n => n.Name == "Folder");
```

I want get something like this :

```
Folder (users)
  |
  |__ Folder (user1)
        |
        |__ Folder (mydocuments)
Folder (windows)
Folder (temp)
```

How is it possible using Linq To Xml ?

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could just remove the files from the folders:

```
doc.Descendants("File").Remove();
```